# Delete connection in Excel using VBA after web scraping

Tags: vba, excel, connection

I have a connection that web scrapes based on a dynamic link. So, I cannot set a fixed connection. The following macro creates the connection and then updates the worksheet.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "<URL redacted>", Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "DataPull"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .Delete
End With
```

This macro runs every 1 minute to update the data. So, this creates a new connection every time it runs. I do not want so many connections to exist as they won't be used anymore. 
How do I delete the connection once web scraping is complete?
or Is there a way to set up a single connection that can modify itself based on a variable. The variable is the time intervals which vary based on current time.

I looked at this option

```
For Each qr In ThisWorkbook.Queries
    qr.Delete
Next qr
```

But there are two other fixed connections which I don't want to delete.
The new connections that are created have the names Connection, Connection1, and so on. Is there a way to delete the connections based on name?

Comment: Did you look at [QueryTables.Add Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytables-add-method-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to delete all connections, except Connection1 and Connection2, try...

```
Dim Conn As WorkbookConnection
For Each Conn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    If Conn.Name <> "Connection1" And Conn.Name <> "Connection2" Then
        Conn.Delete
    End If
Next Conn
```

Hope this helps!